# Restore fragment after lock and unlock screen

Tags: android, android-service

I have 3(A,B,C) fragment and one activity.fragment A added in activity and then fragment B,C replaced.now fragment A replaced with fragment B.in  fragment B i added some details .then i lock the screen after unlock the screen ..it is open activity with fragment A(added).how to restore fragment B after lock and unlock screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the state inside class that extends the `Application` class, cause activity will released after display changed (lock screen occured, or orientation changed).

Your new Application class:

```
public class myApp extends Application {
   public int state; //field that keeps saved state
```

Inside your activity class:

```
//add this method to save changed state
//then call it every time you change the fragment index
private void onChangeFragment(int stateid) {
    myApp sapp = (myApp) this.getApplication(); 
    sapp.state = stateid;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                            

    myApp sapp = (myApp) this.getApplication();              
    //restore fragment from sapp.state value
    switch (sapp.state) {
        case 0 : //fragment A
            {  setContentView(R.layout.fragmentA);
               //maybe Fragment newFragment = new MyFragmentA(); ... and so on
               break;  
            }
        case 1 : //fragment B
            {  setContentView(R.layout.fragmentB);
               //maybe Fragment newFragment = new MyFragmentB(); ... and so on
               break;  
            }
    }
```

And inside manifest
     `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"` ...**android:name=".myApp"**`>

Other way is to use the activity's previously saved state through `Bundle savedInstanceState`.

Inside your activity class:

```
private int state; //field that keeps saved state

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    state = savedInstanceState.getInteger(FRAGMENT_STATE_KEY);
    //restore the fragment from state value here
    //switch (state) {....
    //....
}

// invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    out.putInteger(FRAGMENT_STATE_KEY, state);

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
```

Comment: can you please explained breifly with coding?